# How does GitHub do its fancy page-wipe effect when navigating repositories?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

1. Using a modern browser, go to a project in GitHub (e.g., https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap)
2. Click a subdirectory.

See the page-wipe effect before the subdirectory page loads? How does that work?

**Update:** More specifically, how does this happen perfectly and seamlessly *before* the next page is loaded? Can clicks be delayed? Is the next page loaded in the background?

Comment: Do you mean the animation or the nice url for every slide?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It uses `history.pushState` (part of the HTML5 history API) along with some sliding effects. See [this link](http://pjax.heroku.com/) for a plugin + demo.

Also, just found [Github's blog post](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider) on the topic!

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that github uses jquery, this is probably the answer you're looking for:
http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/